# Ahref links are missing in pagination code using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, pagination

This is my Pagination code, at the bottom of the page, page numbers are displaying but the ahref links are not working. Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong. I hope that you don't require the css file.

Please also notice that the pagination links (ahref links) are created first time but links gets disappeared when I move from one page to another page. (I have not included the connection string.)

```
   <html>
<head> 

<link href="pagin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <?php
/*
    Place code to connect to your DB here.
*/
include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.


$tbl_name="data";       //your table name
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
$adjacents = 3;

/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
echo $query;
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "page3.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 4;                                    
  //how many    items to show per page
$page = isset($_GET['page']);
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
 //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             
    //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql. "<br>". mysql_error());

/* Setup page vars for display. */
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {

    // Your while loop here

    $title = $row['title'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $region = $row['region'];
        $sector = $row['sector'];
        $theme = $row['theme']; 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div class='admonition'>";    
        echo "<div class='admonition-title'>";
        echo "<a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";echo "</div>"; echo "</div>";
        echo "<h4>Sector: $sector&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br> Region: $region <hr> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

    }
?>

<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Comment: What does `echo $row['link'];` give you?

Comment: It may potentially be because you open the <h3> tag twice, rather than close it. `echo "<a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";echo "</div>"; echo "</div>";`

Comment: just a note to warn you that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and no longer supported. It is recommended to switch to using either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libs instead.

Comment: also Change this line:

    `echo "<a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";echo "</div>"; echo "</div>";`

to:


   `echo '<a href="'.$link.'"><h3>'.$title.'<h3></a>';
    echo "</div>"; 
    echo "</div>";`

You seem to have the quotes mixed up. Your href should have it's quotes also.

Comment: Your last <h4> tag lacks an end tag. Please see my answer below. It cases your code to break. the pagination echoed after this line can't display the pagination links. It probably got lost in the excess non-breaking-spaces nbsp; Why not use css float instead to reduce your markup on that line?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I have removed all non-breaking-spaces and closed the H3 and H4 tag. But problem still persists. Links on page number are appearing at the first time when code executes but when I move to another page links disappears.

Comment: Glad to know I've answered your question below. But do find time to mark the answer. It would help others. Especially the extra codes I include in update 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by this:

```
echo "<h4>Sector: $sector&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br> Region: $region <hr> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
```

You don't seem to have an end tag for your  tag.

Use this instead

```
echo "<h4>Sector: $sector&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br> Region: $region </h4><hr> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

It cases your code to break. the pagination echoed after this line can't display the pagination links. It probably got lost in the excess non-breaking-spaces nbsp; Why not use css float instead to reduce your markup on that line?

[UPDATE 3.0]

Do this and let me know what you find (notice the integer casting). For some reason, this works only when I cast $page as integer.

#### I've included additional codes to accommodate the 3 querystrings you specified (k, x, y) If you change them, you'd need to change them in the code too. Also see the additional codes in the links.

```
<?php
    $total_rows = 20;
    $selected_row = mt_rand(0, $total_rows);
    /*
      Place code to connect to your DB here.
     */
//include('config.php');  // include your code to connect to DB.


    $tbl_name = "data";
   
// How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /*
      First get total number of rows in data table.
      If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
     */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
//echo $query;
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "page3.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
    
     //UPDATE 2.0 
     //Create the lines below to get k=world&x=9&y=2 and include links. Please see changes in link below:
    /*
    $k = ((isset($_GET['k']))? "&k=".$_GET['k'] : "" );
    $x = ((isset($_GET['x']))? "&x=".$_GET['x']: "" );
    $y = ((isset($_GET['y']))? "&y=".$_GET['y'] : "" );
    $query_string = $k.$x.$y;
    */
    
    //UPDATE 3.0
    //MORE DYNAMIC should you decide to change the url parameters used.
    $q = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    if($q != ""){
       $q_a = explode('&', $q);
       $q_b = array();
       $q_c = array();
       $link = "";
       foreach($q_a as $param){
           $q_b[] = explode('=', $param);
           foreach($q_b as $key => $value){
               $q_c[$value[0]] = $value[1];
           }
       }
        unset($q_c['page']);
    }
    foreach($q_c as $key => $value){
        $link .= "&";
        $link .= $key.'='.$value;    
    }
    
    $query_string = $link;
    
    $limit = 4;
    //how many    items to show per page
    $page = isset($_GET['page']);
        
    
    $page = $this->uri->segment(3);
    if ($page)
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;
    //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql . "<br>" . mysql_error());

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0)
        $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages / $limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /*
      Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object.
      We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
     */
    $pagination = "";
    if ($lastpage > 1) {
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev{$query_string}\">previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) {   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {

                if ($counter == (int) $page) {
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                } else {
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter{$query_string}\">$counter</a>";
                }
            }
        } elseif ($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) {    //enough pages to hide some
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if ($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2)) {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == (int) $page) {
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    } else {
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter{$query_string}\">$counter</a>";
                    }
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1.$query_string\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage{$query_string}\">$lastpage</a>";
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif ($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2)) {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1{$query_string}\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2{$query_string}\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter{$query_string}\">$counter</a>";
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1{$query_string}\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage{$query_string}\">$lastpage</a>";
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1{$query_string}\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2{$query_string}\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++) {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter{$query_string}\">$counter</a>";
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1)
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next{$query_string}\">next</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        // Your while loop here

        $title = $row['course_title'];
        $link = $row['course_description'];
        $region = $row['course_fee'];
        $sector = $row['diploma_fee'];
        $theme = $row['course_duration'];
        /*
          $title = $row['title'];
          $link = $row['link'];
          $region = $row['region'];
          $sector = $row['sector'];
          $theme = $row['theme'];
         */
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo "<div class='admonition'>";
        echo "<div class='admonition-title'>";
        echo "<a href=$link><h3>$title<h3></a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<h4>Sector: $sector&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Theme: $theme &nbsp; 
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br> Region: $region <hr> </td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>

<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Other than that, everything seems to work fine from my end.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I have removed all non-breaking-spaces and closed the H3 and H4 tag. But problem still persists. Links on page number are appearing at the first time when code executes but when I move to another page links disappears.

Comment: Check the link you clicked if the url was well formed. You should have something like page3.php?page=3 Is that what you get when you clicked? Which of the links did you click and what url was sent. How many records do you have in your db? Start with the url after clicking. At least you can see page links on first page, other should be easy.

Comment: The URL is formed correctly. The URL that I got was "page3.php?page=2" There are 20 records in my db. Please help

Comment: Please quickly modify the line I indicate in the update and commented and let me have your result.

Comment: Hi Steward, Thanks the links on the pagination came back but now pagination doesn't work. I am not able to move from one page to another page. Please help

Comment: It worked where I tested it. I just replaced your database with mine, did the int casting and everything worked. If the links are now displaying, can you post the url before link is clicked and another after you click on a page? I can't figure out your problems immediately because it worked with mine. Please follow all the capitalized comments also.

Comment: Did you include the following line in your code? `$page = isset($_GET['page']);
$page = (int) $page; `. I'm trying to figure out why page was not regarded as an integer. It comes in as String as do most post and get variables. Casting it and editing the database tables, etc got it working. I wish I could get a working example out for you to see.

Comment: Hi, This is the url before I clicked the link http://sambhanot.net84.net/March5/page3.php?k=world&x=9&y=2
This is the link after I clicked the link
http://sambhanot.net84.net/March5/page3.php?page=2
I noticed in the second link the phrase "World" is missing i.e. it is not being passed to the next page (pagination link). It's a word that I am trying to search in the database. There are 18 records in my db and I am displaying 2 per page. PLEASE HELP...!!

Comment: This is a different question from what you asked and your response to comments takes too long. You might want to consider this question answered first by marking it. Then we can talk about fixing your new issue. At least, now you can see the links. To fix this anyway, you need to retrieve the querystring and concatenate them to the link. I'd update my answer to accomodate that but might confuse people seeing it's not part of question.

Comment: Fixed. See Update 2.0. Your code should work now as expected. The rest is up to you. You'd have to confirm if this answers your question or not.

Comment: See update 3.0 for a more dynamic way of getting your querystring. Works even when you decide not to use x, y, z as shown above.

Comment: Thanks Steward, The code is now working for me. Many thanks for your help

Comment: So why haven't you accepted the answer. It takes time to provide answers to questions like these. It's always a good idea to mark the question as answered so others would know the answer worked and learn from it. They won't read this comment, thanks now working. The answer check would make the difference. Hopefully, you'd mark it. I'm glad to know your problem is fixed.

Comment: What's the suggestion here? Should I withdraw my answer?

Comment: Steward, yes you are correct I just marked the question answered.

Comment: Thanks, although it's usually not the best to let people request for an answer to be ticked when it turned out very helpful. I'm glad it did what you wanted and fixed your codes. We'd be here to help anytime.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem:

```
$pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a>";
```

one solution

```
$pagination.= '<a href="' . $targetpage?page=$prev . '">previous</a>';
```